# How to change data between ESP32 and RPI 3 via bluetooth?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I want to send data from ESP32 to Raspberry Pi 3 via BLE, preferentially using Node.js. Any suggestion?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with an android phone:
Here's the ESP32 part

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h";
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SerialBT.begin("My ESP32");
}
void loop(){
 if (SerialBT.hasClient()) {
 
     SerialBT.println("Here is my message");
  }
  delay(200);
}
```

Then you should see how things goes with the raspberry pi3

[More info here](https://medium.com/@mahesh_joshi/raspberry-pi-3-and-arduino-communication-via-bluetooth-hc-05-5d7b6f162ab3)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/noble/noble
https://github.com/noble/bleno

I tested one of them, dont remember which. 
The problem is they require older nodejs, v8.x or v10.x if i remember correct.